# Axios and NodeJS, download image file

Tags: node.js, axios

From frontend I'm calling to an backend service with:

```
return axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: someUrl/${payload}`,
  responseType: 'stream'
})
  .then((resp) => resp.data)
  .catch((err) => err);
```

And I'm receiving a file like this:

```
"����\u0000\u0018Exif\u0000\u0000II*\u0000\b\u0000\u00...(etc)..."
```

The response is a string with double quote of the actual IMG binary file.

In the other side, on the service, I have this:

```
const config = {
  method: 'get',
  url: someExternalUrl/{payload},
};

return axios(config)
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data);
    return response.data;
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

When I do a `console.log` of the response.data I see that string that the frontend receives.

My question is:

How can I send the binary file to the frontend calls?
Or do I have to converte the received string on the frontend?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the backend code to return the response as follows:

```
const config = {
  method: 'get',
  url: someExternalUrl/{payload},
  responseType: 'arraybuffer'
};

return axios(config)
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data);
    return response.data;
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Setting the **responseType** to **arraybuffer**, the response will be returned as a binary buffer instead of a string.

On frontend, you should remove the **.then((resp) => resp.data)** part of the code and use the response directly as binary data:

```
return axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: someUrl/${payload}`,
  responseType: 'arraybuffer'
})
  .catch((err) => err);
```

You can use the binary data in the frontend as needed. Display an image, you can create a blob URL from the binary data:

```
const blob = new Blob([binaryData], { type: 'image/jpeg' });
const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
// Use the URL to display the image in an <img> element
```